# Contribute to RRSP without deducting - how long can the deduction claim be deferred?

Tags: taxes, canada, tax-deduction, rrsp

[This](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45720/contribute-to-rrsp-without-deducting) question establishes that one can contribute to their RRSP without deducting for the year of the contribution.

Additionally, this [link](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/rrsps-related-plans/contributing-a-rrsp-prpp/contributions-affect-your-rrsp-prpp-deduction-limit.html#whtcntrbtnscnyddct) from CRA's site has the question 
"What RRSP, PRPP, or SPP contributions can you deduct on your tax return?" with the answer "your unused RRSP, PRPP or SPP contributions **from a previous year**"

Does this mean that one can contribute to their RRSP but defer the deduction indefinitely? It seems like yes but taxes are very sensitive and if a rule is interpreted incorrectly, it can result in severe penalties. Hence, my paranoia about this. The language on CRA's website is much more explicit regarding RRSP contribution limits and carry forward rules and time frames.

If you have a CRA link that specifies the answer to this more explicitly, that would be appreciated. Please answer this only if you are very knowledgeable about taxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can carry forward unused contributions indefinitely.  The best way to prove it to you would be to read the schedule 7 that you have to fill out in order to carry them forward.

https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/tax-packages-years/general-income-tax-benefit-package/5000-s7.html

Note that just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  In a sense you are loaning Canada the tax return benefit for however many years, interest free.  At some point using the deduction even for a lesser benefit outweighs making long term interest free loans.

One thing that has caused some problems is when people don't put current year first 60 day RRSP contributions on last years schedule 7.  It's not illegal or anything but it confuses the CRA and they start hassling you.  Just read it carefully (and don't do your taxes before March 1st if you're not sure of your contributions).